# How do I use an environment variable in the Xcode Scheme Arguments Passed On Launch window?

Tags: xcode, environment-variables

I'm trying to set up another Xcode project as the one passed on launch for [the purposes of testing an Xcode extension](https://nshipster.com/xcode-source-extensions/):

[image]

Rather than hardcoding a path like this, I'd like to make it relative to the current directory.

I created a placeholder build script and output the environment variables. I found out that the current project directory can be accessed via the `PROJECT_DIR` environment variable.

How do I reference this environment variable in the Arguments Passed On Launch screen?

For example, instead of `/Users/zoesmith/Desktop/Sample/TestableCode.xcodeproj`, I'd like the path to be something like this instead:

```
PROJECT_DIR/../TestableCode.xcodeproj
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the following works:

```
"$(PROJECT_DIR)/../TestableCode.xcodeproj"
```

I think the quotes are required in case `PROJECT_DIR` has any spaces in it.

I'm not sure what the difference is between `$PROJECT_DIR` and `$(PROJECT_DIR)`, but both seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

One additional hint for anyone having trouble getting this working: Make sure the `Expand Variables Based On` setting is *not* set to `None`.

[image]